# Drupal 8 : How to render fields from contact form in twig template

Tags: twig, drupal-8

These are my custom fields in my contact form,

[image: Custom fields: Name and Phone]

I need to render these fields directly in `form.html.twig` template. Is there a way to do it directly using expressions `{{ }}` ??

I tried using these ways:

1. `{{ form.field_name }} {{ form.field_phone }}`
2. `{{ element.field_name }} {{ element.field_phone }}`

Comment: You can use `{{ dump() }}` to see what variables are available!